# Matplotlib pyplot stackplot creates artifacts when antialiasing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am creating stackplots using `matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot` and when there are two regions that are next to each other with the same color, there are some strange antialiasing artifacts that I would like to get rid of.

Here is a simple example to show what I mean:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y0 = [1, 1] + 8*[0]
y1 = np.cumsum(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=10))
y2 = np.cumsum(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=10))
y3 = np.cumsum(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=10))

y2[:3] = 0

colors=['grey', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']

y = np.stack([y0, y1, y2, y3])
im = plt.stackplot(x, y, colors=colors, ec=colors, lw=1)
```

[image]

You can clearly see a white/grey line between the two blocks of data that shouldn't be there.

Changing `ec='none'` or to the facecolor does not change anything (same for lw=0) and setting antialiasing to False is also not necessarily want I want (because I want the antialiasing in a setting that is more complex than the example above). So I just want to get rid of the artifacts between the regions that have the same color.

**EDIT**
I think this is actually a bug in matplotlib and I have posted an issue on their Github: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22386

Comment: setting `ec='blue'` removes the line for me

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the description to a case where that does not help

Comment: at least for me it looks fine **when you don't set the line width to 0** (in this case ec will have no effect of course)

Comment: (I'm using matplotlib version 3.5.1).

Comment: Ok I edited the example one more time and this time it still doesn't work even if lw is not 0